# Let $[G:H]=p$ be prime. If there is an element $g\notin H$ satisfies $gH=Hg$, then $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Suppose $G$ is a group and $H\leq G$ with $[G:H]=p$ is a prime. Then prove if there is an element $g\notin H$ satisfies $gH=Hg$, then $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

**My attempt:**

I tried to consider the normalizer of $H$. Notice that $H\leq N_G(H)$, and as a set, $|G/H|=p>|G/N_G(H)|$. From these I have a feeling that I can show that $N_G(H)=G$ thus $H$ is normal, but I can't get any further... Any help and hints will be appreciated!

Best regards!

Comment: Since $[G:N_G(H)]$ divides $[G:H]=p$, we find it is either $1$ (in which case $N_G(H)=G$ so $H\trianglelefteq G$ is normal) or $p$ (in which case $N_G(H)=H$, so $g\in N_G(H)\setminus H$ is impossible, a contradiction). You can also argue without normalizers... Hint: if $[G:H]=p$ then all elements of $G$ are expressible as $g^kh$ with $0\le k<p$ and $h\in H$.

Comment: @runway44: OHHHH I omitted that $[G:H] = [G:N_G(H)][N_G(H):H]$, thanks!!

Comment: Which definition of "normal" are you using? There are many (equivalent) definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution was indicated by @runway44 in the comments:

Since $H\le N_G(H)\le G$, we have $[G:N_G(H)]\cdot [N_G(H):H]=[G:H]=p\implies N_G(H)=H \lor N_G(H)=G$.

But by assumption $H\subsetneq N_G(H)$, since $g\notin H$ and the inner automorphism induced by $g$ restricts to an automorphism of $H$.

$\therefore N_G(H)=G$.

Comment: (Inner) automorphisms can be omitted by noting that, by assumption, $g\in N_G(H)\setminus H$.

Comment: @Devo well,  sure, I just thought I'd remind you that it's one characterization of the normalizer.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

1. Note that $[G:H]$ prime; $g \not \in H$ $\implies$ $g, H$ together generate the whole of $G$, i.e., $G =\langle g,H \rangle$.
2. So now let $y \in G$. Then from 1., $y$ is in $\langle g, H \rangle$. This, and the equation $gH = Hg$, implies $y$ can be written $y=g^rh$ for some nonnegative integer $r$ and some $h \in H$.
3. Then, letting $y=g^rh$ be as in 2.: $$y^{-1}Hy = h^{-1}g^{-r}Hg^rh$$ $$=h^{-1}g^{-r}g^rHh = H.$$ Used here $r$ times is the relation $gH=Hg$.